# Netbeans platform installer runnable without admin rights?

Tags: installation, netbeans-platform, admin-rights

I have bundled a netbeans platform based application (including a jre, thanks geertjan !) with the fabulous netbeans installer.

When I run the installer on windows (tested it on 7), the system asks me for admin rights. Some of my users won't have such rights, am I stuck ? :(

Is this possible to run the installer without admin rights ?

Answer (score 0):

You could move your netbeans platform project over to maven, you will find that maven will package your build into a useful self contained zip file.  Your users will be able to unzip the zip file anywhere and there will be a exe file for your application in the unzipped bin folder.